# To find average by changing parameters

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

I am trying to use this formula:

```
=Average(D2:D(value(j5)))
```

to find the average from D2:D(whatever parameter I can change in a different Cell).

It doesn't seem to work. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`INDIRECT`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) and [`OFFSET`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-C8DE19AE-DD79-4B9B-A14E-B4D906D11B66) are both useful functions for this. However, they are also volatile, so try not to use them everywhere in your workbook or you might find it affects performance. Thry this:

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("D2:D"&VALUE(J5)))
```

or

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(D2,,,VALUE(J5)-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this has already an accepted answer, but I always try to find solutions, which aren't volatile. So I use the following:

```
=AVERAGE(D2:INDEX(D:D,J5))
```